# Creating a typed ModelState.AddModelError()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, lambda

In a controller I can perform DB lookups etc and add some error message associated with a model property:

```
public ActionResult CreateJob(CreateJobModel viewModel)
{
    var call = FindCall(viewModel.CallNumber);

    if (call == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("CallNumber", "Idiot User!");
    }
}
```

I don't like that CallNumber is a string, when ideally it should refer directly to viewModel.CallNumber, and if I change the name of that property, it should be changed too.

**How can I achieve this?**

I'd imagine the code would end up something like this, which would take a property access expression:

```
AddModelFieldError(() => viewModel.CallNumber, "Idiot User!");
```

But I'm not sure how to create a method like that, or in the case where it's a sub/inner-property that needs the error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would write my own generic extension method:

```
public static class ModelStateDictionaryHelper
{
    public static void AddModelError<TViewModel>(
        this ModelStateDictionary me,
        Expression<Func<TViewModel, object>> lambdaExpression, string error)
    {            
        me.AddModelError(GetPropertyName(lambdaExpression), error);
    }

    private static string GetPropertyName(Expression lambdaExpression)
    {
        IList<string> list = new List<string>();
        var e = lambdaExpression;

        while (true)
        {
            switch (e.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Lambda:
                    e = ((LambdaExpression)e).Body;
                    break;
                case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                    var propertyInfo = ((MemberExpression)e).Member as PropertyInfo;
                    var prop = propertyInfo != null
                                      ? propertyInfo.Name
                                      : null;
                    list.Add(prop);

                    var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)e;
                    if (memberExpression.Expression.NodeType != ExpressionType.Parameter)
                    {
                        var parameter = GetParameterExpression(memberExpression.Expression);
                        if (parameter != null)
                        {
                            e = Expression.Lambda(memberExpression.Expression, parameter);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return string.Join(".", list.Reverse());
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }

    private static ParameterExpression GetParameterExpression(Expression expression)
    {
        while (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            expression = ((MemberExpression)expression).Expression;
        }
        return expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter ? (ParameterExpression)expression : null;
    }
}
```

and the usage:

```
ModelState.AddModelError<CreateJobModel>(x => x.CallNumber, 
                                              "some kind attention");
```

It looks a bit differently from the version you've asked about, but I hope it can be acceptable alternative.

Comment: @Yorro: Good to know, I wasn't aware that `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText` existed in the MVC Framework that time I was providing this answer.

Comment: @Yorro Nice one. I was thinking surely there is a class for this :)

Answer (score 4):

As of C# 6, you can use the `nameof` operator.

```
public ActionResult CreateJob(CreateJobModel viewModel)
{
    var call = FindCall(viewModel.CallNumber);

    if (call == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(CreateJobModel.CallNumber), "Idiot User!");
    }
}
```

Comment: It works only on a single level, i.e. nameof(CreateJobModel.CallNumber), but not nameof(CreateJobModel.CallNumber.Extension).

Comment: If possible(?), I recommend adding all errors of a model property to the same key in the model state dictionary

Comment: It is possible to add all errors to the string.Empty key, but why would you do that in all cases? A key per property makes a lot of sense for proper error reporting. If it is not the case for you, you don't even need a dictionary. Just return an array of errors.

Comment: Can you add multiple errors to a real key? If yes then I would add all the errors in a nested object to that object's key.